# How do I merge two dataframes, one column are the names of all the columns in the other dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

So the question is pretty straight forward I have two dataframes one that looks something like this (first df)

```
  Date    name  info    x
1/2/2007    a   3       s
1/2/2007    b   34      m
1/3/2007    a   23      s
1/4/2007    a   21      m
1/5/2007    b   31      s
1/6/2007    a   35.3    m
1/6/2007    b   39.6    s
1/6/2007    c   43.9    m
1/7/2007    a   48.2    s
1/8/2007    b   52.5    m
1/9/2007    a   56.8    s
1/9/2007    c   61.1    m
1/10/2007   a   65.4    s
1/11/2007   a   69.7    m
1/12/2007   b   74      s
1/13/2007   b   78.3    m
1/14/2007   a   82.6    s
1/14/2007   b   86.9    m
1/14/2007   c   91.2    s
1/14/2007   d   95.5    m
```

Then I have antother dataframe that looks something like this (second df)

```
Date        a      b     c    d
1/2/2007    20     5        
1/3/2007    21     4        
1/4/2007    23     6        
1/5/2007    19     2        
1/6/2007    20.5   7     8  
1/7/2007    20.4   5.4   7  
1/8/2007    20.3   5.6   6  
1/9/2007    20.2   5.8   10 
1/10/2007   20.1   6     9  
1/11/2007   20     6.2   11 
1/12/2007   19.9   6.4   12 
1/13/2007   19.8   6.6   13 
1/14/2007   19.7   6.8   15   20
```

My idea is that I want the end result to be

```
Date       name  info    x     y
1/2/2007    a   3        s    20
1/2/2007    b   34       m     5
1/3/2007    a   23       s    21
1/4/2007    a   21       m    23
1/5/2007    b   31       s     2
1/6/2007    a   35.3     m    20.5
1/6/2007    b   39.6     s     7
1/6/2007    c   43.9     m     8
1/7/2007    a   48.2     s    20.4
1/8/2007    b   52.5     m     5.6
1/9/2007    a   56.8     s    20.2
1/9/2007    c   61.1     m     10
1/10/2007   a   65.4     s    20.1
1/11/2007   a   69.7     m     20
1/12/2007   b   74       s     6.4
1/13/2007   b   78.3     m     6.6
1/14/2007   a   82.6     s    19.7
1/14/2007   b   86.9     m     6.8
1/14/2007   c   91.2     s     15
1/14/2007   d   95.5     m     20
```

Is there any simple way to do this cause the dataframe that I have that looks like the second df is much larger  and the first df is much longer and I don't want to do a super large merge cause the only idea I had was with a merge that includes every single name in second df and that would be eternal to do. If anyone can help me out it would be marvelous. The idea is to do it in python using pandas but I can also do it in excel if anyone now how to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want insert column a

```
pd.merge(df, df2[['a']], how='inner', right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

Or you can merge all columns and drop columns

```
pd.merge(df, df2, how='inner', right_index=True, left_index=True).drop(['b','c','d'],1]
```

Comment: So I just tried your code but umm the merge you are propisng umm works  for a dat frame with only four columns wheras my case can have more then a hundred so typing their names one by one wouldn't be efficient.